# URL amigável htaccess não funciona no Plesk?

Tags: php, htaccess, plesk

Criei o arquivo `.htaccess` e incluí o mesmo na raiz do meu site com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ teste.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ teste.php?u=$1
```

Porém ele está sendo ignorado. Quando eu usava o servidor Linux funcionava de boa.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: aqui tem o que precisa https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/494021-arquivo-htaccess-em-servidor-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é alterar o arquivo `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="exemplo 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="teste.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```